# Why is variable undefined in global object even though it has not been defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, executioncontext

I have this code:

```
console.log(apple);
```

If I run the program, I get the following result:

```
console.log(apple);
            ^

ReferenceError: apple is not defined
```

This is what I expected, but if I modify the code to print the apple variable from the global object, I get undefined

```
console.log(global.apple);
```

Result:

```
undefined
```

How is this undefined? As per my understanding, this should give the ReferenceError too right? Sorry if this is a simple concept, I am trying to understand the fundamentals. Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: "*this should give the ReferenceError too right?*" no, *reading a property* does not throw reference errors, only *reading a variable*.

Comment: `global` is defined (by design). But `global.anything` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're forbidden to do is reference a *standalone identifier* that the interpreter cannot resolve.

Referencing a property of an object - even if the property doesn't exist - is perfectly fine. It will result in `undefined`, but it won't throw.

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.foo);
```